# Translating the "keywords" label (icst class)

Tags: keywords

I'm writing an article for my faculty and I have to use [this](http://eai.eu/transaction/creative-technologies) template. I would like to translate the `keywords` label, at the beginning of the template, to my native language.

I tried:

```
\renewcommand{\keywords}%
{MyTransaltion}
```

which translates it, but also moves it at the top of the template, so this isn't working.

I also set my language with:
    `\selectlanguage{myLanguage}`, which did change a few labels, but not this one.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `icst.cls` file defines `\keywords` at line 214 as

```
\def\keywords#1{%
  \gdef\@keywords{\textbf{Keywords:}\hspace{0.75em}{#1}}}
```

So you can just put

```
\makeatletter
\def\keywords#1{%
  \gdef\@keywords{\textbf{MY TRANSLATION:}\hspace{0.75em}{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble and you are done.